# Zoom not working in Custom UIScrollView

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview, zooming

I have a problem with a *custom* class of `UIScrollView` that I use to hold an `UIImageView` inside of it.

I have another ViewController with a **Main UIScrollView** that I add some objects of the `CustomScrollViewClass` Class. I am trying to enable zooming inside this custom `UIScrollvView` but with no sucess!!!

Everything seems to work fine BUT I cannot zoom the `UIImageView` inside my object from `CustomScrollViewClass`! I have tried a lot of things but nothing worked by now.

```
//CustomScrollViewClass .h file

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CustomScrollViewClass : UIScrollView <UIScrollViewDelegate>
{
    BOOL iPad;
    BOOL iPhone5;

    NSString *imageName;

    UIImageView *imageView;
}

@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *imageName;
@property (nonatomic,strong) UIImageView *imageView;

- (id)initWithImageAndFrame:(CGRect)frame imageName:(NSString*)image;

@end
```

This is the **.m** file

```
//CustomScrollViewClass .m file

#import "CustomScrollViewClass.h"

@implementation CustomScrollViewClass

@synthesize imageName,imageView;

- (id)initWithImageAndFrame:(CGRect)frame imageName:(NSString*)image
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

    if (self) {

        CGRect imagef;

        CGSize screenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;

        if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
            if (screenSize.height > 480.0f) {
                iPhone5 = YES;
                imagef = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 388);
            } else {
                iPhone5 = NO;
                imagef = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 420);
            }
            iPad = NO;
        } else {
            iPad = YES;
            iPhone5 = NO;
            imagef = CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 824);
        }

        self.contentSize = imagef.size;
        self.maximumZoomScale = 2.0;
        self.minimumZoomScale = 1.0;
        self.zoomScale = 1.0;
        self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        self.multipleTouchEnabled = YES;

        imageName = image;

        UIImageView *imageAux = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageName]];
        imageAux.frame = imagef;
        imageAux.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        imageView = imageAux;
        [self addSubview:imageView];

        NSLog(@"%@",imageName);
    }
    return self;
}

-(UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    NSLog(@"%@",@"viewForZoomingInScrollView");
    return self.imageView;
}

- (void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    NSLog(@"%@",@"scrollViewDidZoom");
}

@end
```

As you can see it should work with zoom but it does not! The image appears noarmally. The part of the code I use to add custom views of it is this one (in this example I add 5 custom views in the **Main UIScrollView**):

```
//Method in MainView that I add objects from CustomScrollViewClass

-(void)PrepareScrollView
{
    CGSize scrollviewc;

    //Add Main ScrollView
    UIScrollView *scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] init];

    if (iPad) {
        scrollviewf = CGRectMake(0, 200, 768, 824);
        scrollviewc = CGSizeMake((768 * 5), 824);
    }
    else {
        if (iPhone5){
            scrollviewf = CGRectMake(0, 180, 320, 388);
            scrollviewc = CGSizeMake((320 * 5), 388);
        } else {
            scrollviewf = CGRectMake(0, 60, 320, 420);
            scrollviewc = CGSizeMake((320 * 5), 420);
        }
    }

    scroll.frame = scrollviewf;
    scroll.contentSize = scrollviewc;
    scroll.pagingEnabled = YES;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        CGRect imagef;

        if (iPad) {
            imagef = CGRectMake((i * 768), 0, 768, 824);
        } else {
            if (iPhone5){
                imagef = CGRectMake((i * 320), 0, 320, 388);
            } else {
                imagef = CGRectMake((i * 320), 0, 320, 420);
            }
        }

        //Add Custom ScrollView with UIImageView
        CustomScrollViewClass *AUX = [[ImageView alloc] initWithImageAndFrame:imagef imageName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i%@",i+1,@"_pt.jpg"]];
        [scroll addSubview:AUX];

    }

    self.scrollView = scroll;
    [self.view addSubview:self.scrollView];
}
```

Comment: as i can see in your code `ImageView` itself is subclass of `UIScrollView` so again you are adding it into new scrollview, just add `ImageView *imageViewAux` object in `[self.view addSubview:imageViewAux]`. - Good Luck

Comment: I have renamed my custom class to `CustomScrollViewClass` so it is better to understanding. But yes, CustomScrollViewClass is a subclass of UIScrollView and I am adding objects of it inside the Main UIScrollView using **[scroll addSubview:AUX]**. So after this my UIScrollView object called `scrollView` receives `scroll` and then I  add it to the main view with **[self.view addSubview:self.scrollView]**; Doing that everything is working fine **EXCPET** the zoom inside my `CustomScrollViewClass` objects that are subClass from `UIScrollView`

Comment: what i said is just remove that `scroll` from the code, and directly add your `AUX` into `self.view`, its not able to pass touch to bottom scrollview in your case thats why. just remove that `scroll` the code and add `[self.view addSubview:AUX]`

Comment: But removing my `scroll` that is my **Main ScrollView** I will not have the scrolling function!